# What is playing my SWF?

Tags: actionscript, flash-cs4

Working with ActionScript 3.0, is there a way to determine if my SWF file is been played in the standalone Flash Player or using a browser plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capabilities.playerType does this:

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#playerType

so:

```
if (Capabilities.playerType == "StandAlone") {
trace("standalone")
}
```

Comment: the value for a plugin test is "PlugIn"

Comment: Thank you very much... Exactly what I wanted!